# how can i extract amount from payments and school name only?

Tags: mysql

```
-- Database: `kanda`

-- Table structure for table `payments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payments` (
  `paymentId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` double NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`paymentId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `payments`
--

INSERT INTO `payments` (`paymentId`, `amount`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 3000, '2015-01-13 08:47:46'),
(2, 3000, '2015-01-13 08:47:56');

-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.6
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jan 14, 2015 at 01:28 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.16
-- PHP Version: 5.5.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


--


--
-- Table structure for table `schools`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schools` (
  `schoolId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `paymentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `schoolname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`schoolId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `schools`
--

INSERT INTO `schools` (`schoolId`, `paymentId`, `schoolname`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'westlands primary'),
(2, 2, 'st.johns primary');
```

Comment: i have tried this but its not giving anything --- SELECT * FROM schools INNER JOIN payments ON schools.schoolname = payments.amount;

Comment: change your condition to `schools.paymentId = payments.paymentId`

Comment: @M Khalid ,you are correct ,thanks it has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With:

```
SELECT * FROM schools INNER JOIN payments ON schools.schoolname = payments.amount;
```

You're trying to match schoolname to the amount, this will always fail

Try:

```
SELECT schools.name, payments.amount FROM schools INNER JOIN payments ON schools.paymentId = payments.paymentId;
```

Comment: Oh and try and be more clear with your question and what you've already tried the next time so you won't get downvoted so quickly

Comment: the question is straight forward, i only need two columns from both tables namely --schoolname and amount .

Comment: you have complicated it further by saying SELECT s.name,p.amount ....from schools s ...it didnt work since i didnt understand your initials..

Comment: @mpile is this better?

Comment: yes thanks ,the i just changed the column name for schools.name to fit mine as schoolname ..perfect.